# Einstein Analytics Recipe Error

Tags: einstein-analytics

I have a Dataflow wherein i have used an augument Transformation which always gives me a  warning when dataflow runs:
**The dataflow was completed, but the LookupSingleValue node didn't augment any columns. Either the node didn't find any matches, or a join key contains only null values.**

Now i have a recipe which is referencing the above Dataflow and doing a self join to it.This recipe always fails because of the augment present in the Dataflow which returns no data for augment transformation.

Please suggest how can i avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer!
In such cases we need to make sure that all columns in the recipe have some data or you can drop the columns which have no data before running the recipe.